# Numpy mean now requires reshape?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to subtract all the values in a numpy array by the average of the column.

previously, the following code worked:

```
centered_data = data - data.mean(axis = 1)
```

Now this code produces error messages like this:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,862) (3,)

changing this line to:

```
centered_data = data - data.mean(axis = 1).reshape(data.shape[0],1)
```

data is of type numpy.ndarray.

Why does the mean vector **now** need a reshape, when it didn't before?

Answer (score 3):

`np.mean` has a `keepdims` parameter.  (`data.mean` has it as well, but it is documented in `np.mean`):

```
In [642]: data=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [643]: data.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[643]: 
array([[ 1.5],
       [ 5.5],
       [ 9.5]])

In [644]: data-data.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[644]: 
array([[-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5]])
```

Without this, operations like `mean` and `sum` remove a dimension.  `reshape(-1,1)` and `[:,None]` also work to add a dimension back in.

If you'd taken the mean on the other axis, you wouldn't need to keep (or restore) the dimensions.  That's because broadcasting rules automatically add a dimension at the start if needed:

```
In [645]: data-data.mean(axis=0)
Out[645]: 
array([[-4., -4., -4., -4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
```

Was your 'before' case like this - reduction on `axis=0`?

I'm not aware of any changes in `numpy` that would have enabled the `axis=1` case without some sort of reshape or keepaxis.

---

If `data.shape==(3, 4)`

```
data+np.array([1,1,1,1])
# data+np.array([1,1,1,1])[None,:]  # automatic None
```

works.

This raises a value error:

```
data+np.array([1,1,1])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3)
```

This works:

```
data+np.array([1,1,1])[:,None]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
data #has shape (3,862)
mean = data.mean(axis=1)  #has shape (3,)
```

According to the first broadcasting rule:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> they are equal, or one of them is 1

so comparing 3 with 862 fails. Hence you need either to reshape data to (862,3) or mean to (3,1).

Comment: I like this explanation to supplement the docs: [EricsBroadcastingDoc](http://wiki.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an axis to an array so that it will broadcast.

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
>>> m = a.mean(-1)
>>> a.shape, m.shape
((3, 8), (3,))
>>> a - m[:, np.newaxis]
array([[-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5],
       [-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5],
       [-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5]])
>>> 
>>> m[:, np.newaxis].shape
(3, 1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q** : "Why does the mean vector now need a reshape?".

**A** : Because NumPy couldn't perform an operation between `(n,m)`and `(n,)`. To broadcast, NumPy looks for axes compatibility, and `1` is compatible with any axis.

```
(3,862) -
(3,) # error
(3,1) # this works
(1,1) # this works
(,862) # error
(1,862) # works
```